# how to display selected records in descending order bases on last id MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display MySQL database selected records in descending order based on the last id. but it's not working please see the SQL statement below

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE catagory='$pro' AND id >($id) LIMIT 6 DESC
```

I want to show only 6 records at a time.

Comment: you typed "catagory". If it's not the reason, please show us the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

add an order by eg:

```
  SELECT * FROM 
  product WHERE catagory='$pro' AND id >($id) 
  ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 6
```

but you should not use  php var in sql you are at risk for sql injection

take a look at your sql driver for use binding param

Comment: this should depend from you data so update your question add  a prper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: answer  update  ..  ..  changedc wrong limit position

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  product
WHERE
  catagory = '$pro'
  AND id > ($id)
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer if you have time so it can be useful to other users in the future.